# Change html contents of div when a specific anchor is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a one-page scrolling site with changing backgrounds. I have a static footer that says 'scroll down' but when the user reaches the last page/anchor I want it to disappear or say 'end'.

My code is a mish-mash of other things I have found on Stack Overflow but here goes:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        $('.section').each(function () {
            var section = $(this).attr('href');
            if (section === "#4thPage") {
                document.getElementById("scrolldown").innerHTML = "newtext";
                currentSection = section;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

On JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charleskh/X5Kqe/13/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is to check for the position of the last element of interest you want against the scrollTop value of the viewport — if the scrollTop position exceeds that (i.e. you have scrolled past the element), which can be evaluated by using a conditional statement, you can perform the action you want:

```
$(function () {
    // You should consider throttling the firing of the scroll event for better performance
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        // 1. Get position where you want the element to disappear
        //    You should update the selector as you see fit
        // 2. Get scroll position along the y-axis with .scrollTop
        var threshold = $('.section[href*="4thPage"]').offset().top,  // #1
            scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();                          // #2

        // Compare threshold and scrollY
        if(scrollY > threshold) {
            $('#scrolldown').text('newtext');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/X5Kqe/16/

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit overkill, but I was doing something similar recently and seeing this post I was inspired to rewrite it as a plugin.

Here are the plugins (examples at bottom):

```
function isFunction(f) {
    var getType = {};
    return f && getType.toString.call(f) === '[object Function]';
}

$.prototype.scrollPosition = function(topPos, options) {
    var self = this;
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        var yPos = isFunction(topPos) ? topPos.call(this) : topPos;

        if($(this).scrollTop() > yPos) {
             if(isFunction(options.scrollPast) &&
               (typeof(this.lastScrollTop) === "undefined" || this.lastScrollTop <= yPos))
                options.scrollPast.call(self);
        }
        else if(isFunction(options.scrollReturn) &&
               (typeof(this.lastScrollTop) === "undefined" || this.lastScrollTop > yPos))
            options.scrollReturn.call(self);

        this.lastScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    });
}

$.prototype.scrollAt = function(options, includeMargins) {
    var self = this;
    $(this).scrollPosition(function() {
        var topPos = $(self).offset().top;
        if(includeMargins)  {
            topPos -= parseInt($(self).css('margin-top'));
        }
        return topPos;
    }, options);
}

$.prototype.scrollPast = function(options, includeMargins) {
    var self = this;
    $(this).scrollPosition(function() {
        return $(self).offset().top + $(self).outerHeight(includeMargins);
    }, options);
}
```

---

**Examples**

In below example, it will call the `scrollPast` callback when you have past the y-coordinate 100, and `scrollReturn` after coming from >= 100 back to < 100.

```
$(element).scrollPosition(100, {
    scrollPast: function() {
        console.log("REACHED", $(this));
    },
    scrollReturn: function() {
        console.log("BEFORE", $(this));
    }
});
```

You may also use a function callback that returns a position, in the place of the fixed position (being 100 in previous example). Demonstrated in below example, the elements actual position is considered despite if it changes.

```
$(element).scrollPosition(function() {
    return $(this).offset().top;
}, {callbacks etc...});
```

Similarly, the two implementations `.scrollAt` and `.scrollPast` are using this method. `.scrollAt` takes effect when the element is just about to escape your screen (optionally considers margin) while `.scrollPast` takes effect when it's outside your screen (also margin is optional). Example usage (same parameters for both):

```
$(element).scrollPast({
    scrollPast: function() {
        console.log("REACHED", $(this));
    },
    scrollReturn: function() {
        console.log("BEFORE", $(this));
    }
}, true);
```

The callback name will always be `scrollPast`, for all of those implementations. Therefore, the `.scrollAt` would look like this:

```
$(element).scrollAt({
    scrollPast: function() {
        console.log("REACHED", $(this));
    },
    scrollReturn: function() {
        console.log("BEFORE", $(this));
    }
}, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the offset value (top) of that anchor, and make a condition to compare it with the value of window scrolled.